# create a percentage allotment where a value x is return 20% of time, value y is returned 35% of time, value z

Tags: java

So it seems very simple right?  I have x,y,z  values...   When I call a function getNextValue() I need x to be returned for 20% of those times, I need y to be returned for 45% of those calls and z returned 35% of the time when function is called.

So I created a hashmap that contains as key integers 1-100.  I filled up the map as such:
map keys 1-20 has value x
map keys 21-65  has values y
map keys 66-100  has values z

so I use  java's Random  to do random.nextInt(100) which returns a random number between 1-100 and then I call the map.get( random.nextInt(100))  which gives me this ratio.

so this returns x 20% of time.  returns y 45% of time.  return z 35 % of time.

But I am looking for something a lot more simple. I know there is something out there maybe using mod or bit shifting but I just can't think of any.   A simple 2-3 liner.

Oh God why can't I do this simpler.

Anyone please ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't really get it.. can't you just do something like:

```
Random r = new Random();

int getNextValue()
{
  float t = r.nextFloat();
  // t will be in [0,1] range

  if (t < 0.2f)
    return x;
  else if (t < 0.65f)
    return y;
  else
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks much for these suggestions.  If I may thrown in a caveat....  

What happens if I have  w,x,y,z   with this ratio:

w return 20%
x return 20%
y returns 35%
z returns 25%

furthermore the assigned ratios to w,x,y,z are configured at runtime so I don't know what they are ahead of time...

so would that be something like:

if (t < 0.2f )
return w
else if (t < 0.4f )
return x
else if (t < 0.75% )
return y
else 
return z

is there easier way of doing it ?

thanks much

Answer (score 2):

If you really only want a few lines, does Java have the conditional operator?

```
Random r = new Random();

int getNextValue()
{
t = r.nextRandom()
return  t < 0.65f ? (t < 0.2f ? x : y) : z;
}
```

Comment: I mean, if you really want to copy my snippet and shorten it, _at least_ try to avoid evident things like your `t` variable that comes from nowhere :)

Comment: Whoops! Glad you can seem to see the humor Jack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe either solution will work. If you use random, it could pick #1 10 times out of 10.

I don't think you can accomplish what you want without keeping track of requests and previous responses. Percentage is a number in relation to a whole. Whats you're whole value?

For example, if I call this function 1 time and it returns X, the function has returned X 100% of the time.

Comment: I think it's implied that the _expected value_ of the percentages are as listed, while in reality it may return #2 a hundred times in a row for a specific run.

Comment: @waxwing, I also originally inferred that the percentages were expected values.  I also inferred that a random order was desired.  However, strictly speaking neither was asked for.

Comment: I think you are right. With random number generation, there is no gaurantee that I will get the % numbers consistently.    It can be argued that we have even random distribution but if I were to call the function 100 times, will I for sure get "x" 20% of time.  If I called it 10K times, I might get the results I want more consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Let n be the total number of x, y, and z you want.

1. Create a List of size n.

   1. Add x to the list 0.20n times.
   2. Add y to the list 0.35n times.
   3. Add z to the list 0.45n times.
2. If you want use Collections.shuffle on the list.
3. Get a list iterator.